# Scaffold Add Controller dialog has empty Data Context class drop-down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, datacontext, scaffolding

I'm using the linq to sql database first approach and have generated my data classes DBML file by adding a connection to the database (under Servers panel) and dragging my tables to the design surface.

In the designer file (Intrinsic.designer.cs) I can clearly see the 'IntrinsicDataContext' is defined but when I attempt to scaffold the controller with views, the Data Context Class dropdown is empty.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="IntrinsicRoadrunner")]
public partial class IntrinsicDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

        private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
```

Everything is one project so there are no namespace issues and I have performed the usual 'clean', 'build', 'rebuild' repeat exercises several times with no benefit. I even dumped all the files and started from scratch with exactly the same proble

I can manually reference the data context class within an existing controller as below:

```
IntrinsicDataContext dbContext = new IntrinsicDataContext();
var drivers = dbContext.Drivers;
```

I believe my web.config provides the correct connection string as this was created using the add connection wizard within the Servers panel and enabled me to drag the tables onto the designer surface.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="IntrinsicRoadrunnerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MACBOOKPRO\ID31898;Initial Catalog=IntrinsicRoadrunner;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Intrinsic;Password=myPassword"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is also referenced in the designer file:

public IntrinsicDataContext() :

```
base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntrinsicRoadrunnerConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }
```

I'm not sure what else to try in order to get the context showing in the Data Context Class scaffolding drop down list?

Comment: have you tried using entity framework instead of linq to sql?  what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: No I haven't tried using EF instead of Linq to SQL... I'll look into that. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013.

Comment: make sure you recompile your solution after you add the edmx model before you try to add your controller or the new models and context class won't show up in the list

Comment: OMG. All my problems solved! As someone who has never worked from an existing database and always created POCOs through code first. Using EF instead of Linq to SQL was far more intuitive. Choosing the option to generate 'Code First from Database' (rather than 'EF Designer from database') gave me a set of model classes that were entirely familiar to the way I usually work. This is definitely my preferred approach. @user1221684, if you post this a suggested answer I will accept.